# How to prevent default title setting on Vue Component?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue Material Design Icons [ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-material-design-icons), and they automatically have a title attribute set - by default it is a human readable form of the icon's name, e.g. *Plus Icon*.  Because this is being imported directly from the Node Package, I don't want to mess with the components themselves.  I also know that I could write some custom JS to fix it, but I don't really want to do that.

Is there a standard way to disable the title attribute during component registration or in some other fashion that doesn't add a performance cost or require any patchwork code?

note: I'm also using Webpack if this can be done that way.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you've provided, that icon component provides a prop where you can set the title to whatever you wish if you don't want to use the default.

> Props
>
> ```
> title - This changes the hover tooltip as well as the title shown to screen readers. By default, those values are a "human readable"
> ```
>
> conversion of the icon names; for example chevron-down-icon becomes
>   "Chevron down icon".
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> <android-icon title="this is an icon!" />
> ```

Comment: Right - but if I don 't set it, it automatically sets it.  I don't want to set it.  I want to remove it.

Comment: So setting it to an empty string wouldn't be a solution for you?

Comment: Maybe.  But that takes a lot of extra markup to undo something that I didn't do to start with.  I was hoping there was a way to do it during build time.

Comment: you could write a component that wraps the functionality of the icon and sets the title to an empty string and then just use your custom component instead?